# Downcase string in array ruby

Tags: ruby

I have some strange thing with `downcase` and `upcase` my string in array. Share my code:

[image: code example]

Comment: Please post it in coding format which is preferable, do not post image where not needed! And most important, what is your question/problem?

Comment: I suspect it is not alphabet and can be symbol like `ℳ` which cannot be down-cased!

Comment: Looks like you have locale settings issue or using an old version of ruby with non-unicode-aware downcase.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the issue is that you do not have correctly encoded strings.

```
foo = ['МеНше', '4.5']
foo.map(&:downcase) #=> ["менше", "4.5"]
foo.each { |el| puts el.downcase }
#>> менше
#>> 4.5
foo.first.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

The first step would be to check your encoding. If it's not UTF-8, you can coerce a `downcase` by doing:

```
foo.each { |el| puts el.mb_chars.downcase.to_s }
#>> менше
#>> 4.5
```

This solution requires Rails, so you'd need to do

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

If you're using plain old ruby.